# Windows Update Error Code 80248014?

Tags: windows, windows-update

Windows Update says:

> Windows could not search for new updates.

Error code is 80248014. What this error code means and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `wuerror.h` I can find that `80248014` means `WU_E_DS_UNKNOWNSERVICE`:

```
//
// MessageId: WU_E_DS_UNKNOWNSERVICE
//
// MessageText:
//
// An operation did not complete because the service is not in the data store.
//
#define WU_E_DS_UNKNOWNSERVICE           _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80248014L)
```

stop the Windows Update service, rename the folder `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` to `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.old`, now check for Updates again. This sometime solves such strange errors.

Comment: wuerror.h? What is this?

Comment: @RichM this is a file from Windows SDK which includes includes windows update error codes

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar problem. After employing a similar fix to the one mentioned by magicandre with no success, I discovered that something was amiss with DNS. I was trying to browse a website from the affected machine and the default IIS entry kept coming up. So, I changed my DNS servers in my network adapter to use Google's public DNS servers, cleared my DNS cache, and was able to check for updates.

Short version, if it's still a problem, it could be DNS related.

Comment: Does it display the **same** (not similar!) error code?

Comment: No, it was not the same, but my point is that Windows error reporting can be vague or inconclusive at best. I am merely suggesting that DNS could be an issue as it was with me, even though I could find no documentation on the Microsoft site or any other site to point me that direction.

Answer (score -2):

1. IN THE RUN BOX, I TYPED SERVICES.MSC
2. I RIGHT CLICKED IN WINDOWS UPDATE SERVICES AND STOP THE SERVICE
3. I RIGHT CLICKED THE FOLDER C:\WINDOWS\SOFTWAREDISTRIBUTION AND SELECTED RENAME
   4  I ADDED JUST .OLD TO THE ORIGINAL NAME OF THE FOLDER.